# YUI 2.9 treeview dynamic loading

Tags: ajax, yui

I have a YUI tree for which dynamic loading (type: MenuNode) is set to true and it works fine. However, there is a scenario where I have to preselect one of the nodes during the initialization process.

I tried creating the nodes during the initialization of the tree and added them appropirately. However 'node.expanded=true' does not expand the node (though node.children.length gives me the correct count).

Any pointers would be of great help.

-Chris